# All Capybara steps pass, but scenario fails

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I have a particular flaky test. Sometimes it fails sensibly and tells me which step went bad. But sometimes it fails the scenario without failing any steps:

```
Using the default profile...
............................F

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/admin/staff_allocation.feature:43 # Scenario: Staff Allocation shows current data

1 scenario (1 failed)
19 steps (19 passed)
0m6.173s
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795854/cucumber-test-double-scenario-failing-but-its-steps-passing) made me suspect the issue was an assertion in a "When" step (as opposed to a "Then" step) but I can't find any trace of such a thing in my steps. Is there any other reason a scenario would fail when all of its steps pass?

Comment: I threw a bunch of gem updates at this ("bundle update everything related to cucumber") and now it seems to fail reliably on a step... when it fails, because it passes when run in isolation, but that's a different question. Still puzzled by this one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any useful information from rspec?  Try using rspec --format to get some of the information you need

Try to experiment with putting 'sleep 5' at the last line of your scenario.  It's possible that you have a faulty assertion near the end of your test and something funky is happening when the scenario completes and capybara does its cleanup at the end.

Comment: This is cucumber, not rspec, but I'll see if there's a verbose mode that will help. I'll try the sleep as well, but obviously that has to be a debugging step, not a solution...